# How to display half of the text of a <li> element in a new line

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Here how can i make this li to display half contents in new line</li>
                <li>Item 5</li>
                <li>Item 6</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</html>
```

Here, in the above code, how can I display half the text in the `<li>` tag in next line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a beginner level question, an `<ul>`'s `<li>` is a block element, unless you assign a width to the parent or the `<ul>` itself - **text won't wrap!** FYR, I just assign width to parent `<ul>`, you can assign a width to the child `<ul>`, too:

```
ul { 
    width: 200px;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tr06h608/)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Here how can i make this li to <br/> display half contents in new line</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Just add the `<br/>` tag where you want the next line to start.
Also if you want to do it using only css just make `width:50%` in the styling.

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li style="width:50%;">Here how can i make this li to display half contents in new line</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```